# When you create a temporary table from another table how do you prevent auto incrementing ids?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datatable

I am currently exporting a portion of a database as XML via a datatable, and also need to be able to re-import the data again.

I've been following http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/ In order to bulk import the data, but it seems that after exporting and re-importing into the temporary table the id values are changing.

I suspect they are being thrown away and the auto increment on the temporary table (made using 
"select top 0 * into #import from tblJob;") is causing the ID to become corrupt as when I edit the XML files and reimport it is updating the wrong rows

Comment: While importing don't include the `IDENTITY` column. that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let SqlBulkCopy know that you want to keep the identity values from your source data with `SqlBulkCopyOptions` like so:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "#Prices";
    bulk.WriteToServer(table);

}
```

Comment: How can I do this using the existing connection? VS wants a string for the constructor of SQLBulkCopy instead of a connection, but if I use the same connection as above it errors out because it is presumably already connected.

Comment: What is the error you get when you pass in your existing connection?

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the identity intact on a reimport:

first, make sure the originating records no longer exist (as i'm assuming your identity is also a primary key)

second,

```
set identity_insert on [table]

import your records

set identity_insert off [table]
```

If you are doing a bulk insert task, there is also a option under... mappings? to "enable identity insert"